# Why does tf.Session().run() not work here?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to figure out why does Session.run() gives a **Session Graph is empty** error. Why does **Session.run()** not work here? Somehow, I can just **print(prediction)** to retrieve the result.

Don't I need to use Session.run() to **start constructing the model** to get prediction?

```
def new_samples():
        #return np.array([[5.9,3,4.2,1.5],[6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1]], dtype=np.float32)
        return np.array(test_data_values, dtype=np.float32)

    predictions = list(classifier.predict_classes(input_fn=new_samples))

    default_session = tf.Session()
    print(default_session.run(predictions))
```

Note: classifier = **tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier**

Comment: You should construct the model before you start a session. A session will then run the tensors through your constructed model (graph) to get your usual outputs (like numpy arrays), so you don't need to use sess.run to construct a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DNNClassifier` is an [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator) which is an abstraction which handles things like sessions for you.
The motivation for the higher level APIs (like `Estimator` or `DNNClassifier`) is precisely this, so you don't have to worry about it. Also it gets more tricky to manage sessions once you have more workers and that is all being handled for you :)

Comment: So basically, at this line here:                                                          
          `predictions = list(classifier.predict_classes(input_fn=new_samples))`  The graph is computed (similar to `tf.Session().run()`) and value of predictions is computed?

Comment: That's the idea, yeah